# Magnific Popup Callback when closing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, magnific-popup

I am using [Magnific Popup](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/) for uploading images. When the user clicks or presses the close button, I'd like to get confirmation from the user whether to close on not.

This is my Javascript:

```
$('#upload').magnificPopup({
    type:'inline',
    callbacks: {
        close: function(){
            if( confirm("Are you sure you want to close?") ) {
              return true;
            }
              return false;
            }
          }
      }
});
```

But it is not working.

Answer (score 11):

You can [override the close method](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#how_to_override_some_function_without_modifying_the_source_files). By modifying the `instance`, you will only change the functionality of this specific popup. Then simply call the original `close` method to finish the job.

```
$('#upload').magnificPopup({
  type:'inline',
  callbacks: {
    open: function() {
      $.magnificPopup.instance.close = function() {
        // Do whatever else you need to do here
        var confirmed = confirm("Are you sure you want to close?");
        if(!confirmed) {
          return;
        }

        // Call the original close method to close the popup
        $.magnificPopup.proto.close.call(this);
      };
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try:

```
( '#upload' ).magnificPopup({
    type: 'inline',
    callbacks: {
      close: function(){
         var didConfirm = confirm( "Are you sure?" );
         if( didConfirm == false ){
            return false;
         }
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. you compressed my question. Not Working

Comment: @Mifas i think the real problem is wid returning the value ,why do u want top retun the value of confirmbox?,its just diverting the original flow of the close function

Comment: @Mifas i think it will work now (its already working with me)

Comment: @CodeHunter I've created a demo based on your answer. Please check if its working or not http://jsfiddle.net/K9Geq/

Comment: I found @CodeHunter's answer to work fine for my needs.

Comment: I 2nd @Toast, Works fine for me too! I overlooked the need to create a callback object but thats the trick!

Comment: This is for sure the better way